# How to send email?

Tags: php, html

i am working on sending email to any recipient like yahoo gmail 
my code is
contact form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email Form </title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="sendeail.php">

<!-- DO NOT change ANY of the php sections -->
<?php
$ipi = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$httprefi = getenv ("HTTP_REFERER");
$httpagenti = getenv ("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
?>

<input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ipi ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="httpref" value="<?php echo $httprefi ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="httpagent" value="<?php echo $httpagenti ?>" />


Your Name: <br />
<input type="text" name="visitor" size="35" />
<br />
Your Email:<br />
<input type="text" name="visitormail" size="35" />
<br /> <br />
<br />
Attention:<br />
<select name="attn" size="1">
<option value=" Sales n Billing ">Sales n Billing </option> 
<option value=" General Support ">General Support </option> 
<option value=" Technical Support ">Technical Support </option> 
<option value=" Webmaster ">Webmaster </option> 
</select>
<br /><br />
Mail Message:
<br />
<textarea name="notes" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send Mail" />
<br />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and senemail.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Sendemail Script</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Reminder: Add the link for the 'next page' (at the bottom) --> 
<!-- Reminder: Change 'YourEmail' to Your real email --> 

<?php

$ip = $_POST['ip']; 
$httpref = $_POST['httpref']; 
$httpagent = $_POST['httpagent']; 
$visitor = $_POST['visitor']; 
$visitormail = $_POST['visitormail']; 
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$attn = $_POST['attn'];


if (eregi('http:', $notes)) {
die ("Do NOT try that! ! ");
}
if(!$visitormail == "" && (!strstr($visitormail,"@") || !strstr($visitormail,"."))) 
{
echo "<h2>Use Back - Enter valid e-mail</h2>\n"; 
$badinput = "<h2>Feedback was NOT submitted</h2>\n";
echo $badinput;
die ("Go back! ! ");
}

if(empty($visitor) || empty($visitormail) || empty($notes )) {
echo "<h2>Use Back - fill in all fields</h2>\n";
die ("Use back! ! "); 
}

$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;

$attn = $attn ; 
$subject = $attn; 

$notes = stripcslashes($notes); 

$message = " $todayis [EST] \n
Attention: $attn \n
Message: $notes \n 
From: $visitor ($visitormail)\n
Additional Info : IP = $ip \n
Browser Info: $httpagent \n
Referral : $httpref \n
";

$from = "From: $visitormail\r\n";


mail("YourEmail", $subject, $message, $from);

?>

<p align="center">
Date: <?php echo $todayis ?> 
<br />
Thank You : <?php echo $visitor ?> ( <?php echo $visitormail ?> ) 
<br />

Attention: <?php echo $attn ?>
<br /> 
Message:<br /> 
<?php $notesout = str_replace("\r", "<br/>", $notes); 
echo $notesout; ?> 
<br />
<?php echo $ip ?> 

<br /><br />
<a href="contact.php"> Next Page </a> 
</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

what changes i have to made in my localhost so that i would be able to send the mail...

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really agree with Kau-Boy that PHP Mailer is must to send the email from Local Host. You have to include mail.php in the mail module to make your application compatible with the localhost. You have to make few changes in settings like Port Number, Host name etc. After that you will be able to send email from Local Host.

This link will help to understand the concept of Sending Email from Local Host

http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading:

[So You'd Like to Send Some Email (Through Code)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)

Comment: But he was not asking for a ruby solution!

Comment: I thought he was asking how he would have to change his machine to send emails. That link talks about all the steps needed, regardless of language.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to use the [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com).

**EDIT**: To be able to send mails thourgh your localhost, you either need to have a mail server running on your local machine or you connect to a STMP server you have an account on. The second can not be done with the mail() function of PHP but with the PHPMailer ([see this example](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp)).

Comment: I agree with this, if you look at my link it's a pretty difficult feat.

Comment: how to use that service
Please suggest.

Comment: If you have XAMPP running on your localhost there is a mail server included. If your don't want to run your own mail server, just send it through a mail service you have an account on. If you have a hosting service you will even be able to send mails with any e-mail address. How to set up the XAMPP mail server, you can found here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QnfF64rA78